# Expected object to be a kind of ScalarObservable, but was Observable

Tags: typescript, jasmine, rxjs, angular-observable, angular-test

In my Angular application, I was using Observables in the following way:

```
getItem(id): Observable<Object> {
  return this.myApi.myMethod(...); // returns an Observable
}
```

and I unit tested it:

```
it('getItem(...) should correctly do its job',
  inject([MyService], (service: MyService) => {

    const spy = spyOn(myApi, 'myMethod').and.returnValue(mockObservable);

    const mockObservable = Observable.of('mock');

    expect(service.getItem(123)).toEqual(mockObservable);

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
  })
);
```

and it worked perfectly fine.

However if I try to add a [default error-handling logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453181/rxjs-how-to-return-observable-with-default-error-handling-function) to my `getItem()` method using `catch`:

```
getItem(id): Observable<Object> {
  return this.myApi.myMethod(...).catch(e => {
    /* display a notification error ... */
    return Observable.throw(e);
  });
}
```

it still works fine but now the test are failing, saying:

> Expected object to be a kind of ScalarObservable, but was Observable({ _isScalar: false, source: ScalarObservable({ _isScalar: true, value: 'mock', scheduler: null }), operator: CatchOperator({ selector: Function, caught:  }) }).

what does it mean? why does it happen? how can I solve this issue?

Comment: `catch` is an operator, so it returns an new observable with the observable you were expecting as it's `source`. That's how operators are implemented.

Comment: To expand on @cartant 's comment.  The check `expect(service.getItem(123)).toEqual(mockObservable)` fails because they are not the same object.  The service method is returnning a new observable that wraps `mockObservable` and so the check fails.  Your test would be better off subscribing to the observable returned from your service call and ensuring it returns `'mock'`.

Comment: thanks @Pace, this actually solves my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @Pace's input:

> `expect(service.getItem(123)).toEqual(mockObservable)` fails because
>   they are not the same object. The service method is returnning a new
>   observable that wraps mockObservable and so the check fails. Your test
>   would be better off subscribing to the observable returned from your
>   service call and ensuring it returns `'mock'`

I found the solution:

```
it('getItem(...) should correctly do its job',
  inject([MyService], (service: MyService) => {

    const spy = spyOn(myApi, 'myMethod').and.returnValue(mockObservable);

    const mockData = 'mock'; // can be anything
    const mockObservable = Observable.of(mockData);


    service.getItems().subscribe((data) => {
      expect(data).toEqual(mockData);
    });

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
  })
);
```

Comment: Just be careful with that sort of test.  If the observable returned from `getItems` is asynchronous then that `expect` may never get called.  For example, you could change `getItems` to be  `this.myApi.myMethod(...).map(() => 'not-mock').delay(500);` and the test will still pass.  One workaround is to change the `expect` to look like...`return service.getItems().do(() => { expect(data).toEqual(mockData); }).toPromise()` and use something like `jasmine-promise`.  There are other ways to do that as well.